# Big O(average) Access time for trees, and hashes

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, big-o

I'm looking for Big O notation - avereage , for only the access of one element.  Here is what I have so far. Once again that is Big O, Average, Access.  Actually I only need it for a Searchable Red and Black Tree and a simple Modulus Hash.

Arrays - O(1)
Linked Lists - O(X)
Trees(defined above) - ?
Hashes(defined above) - ?

[image]

Comment: Is this no Language Independent? Why is it tagged C++?

Comment: Honestly, get your hands on a copy of this book: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318613724&sr=8-1. It can answer every question you'd ever have on common algorithms, including this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tree = O(log n)

Hashtable = O(1)

Comment: For tree that log is base 2? Hash makes sense

Comment: @ChrisAaker: The base in the `log` does not matter since all log functions are the same to a multiplicative constant, and the multiplicative constant is masked by the big-Oh.

Comment: the base is irrelevant.  log(2) n = ln n / ln 2.  same for any base -- you're dividing by a constant.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is wrong, but the big-Oh notation does not consider these constants.  For example it doesn't matter if a linear algorithm traverses a list once, twice or 100 times, the complexity would still be O(n). Read a good post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Comment: Yes, it is for a balanced binary tree since each traversal between nodes cuts the remaining nodes to check in half. But it is still not relevant for big-o notation.